# AS3 - Loading different XML files through drag and drop?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, drag-and-drop

[image]

Hello, I decided to use another image to show what my goals are, I want to know if it’s possible to load multiple XML’s files whenever a successful drag and drop has been made? And if it’s possible to reset or switch to a blank XML when taken off the target goal?

My code has been mixed with my other code, basically if the circles were buttons, it would load a different XML each time, I want to more or less merge the two sets of code so that when the circle/statue is dragged over, "Circle one In Place Successfully" message will appear and the xml file I have will load as well. When I tried to implement it the overall result sadly was countless errors which left me at a stump I'm afraid to say.

Oh, I also want to make this clear as well, this isn't an offset from my previous question about drag and drop, this is more of me trying out different approaches for and learning about XML in general so I ended up using this as a "skeleton" for testing a situation if it's possible to load different XML at each drag.

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;

var circles:Array = [circle1_mc, circle2_mc, circle3_mc];

circle1_mc.myname = "xmlFile1";
circle2_mc.myname = "xmlFile2";
circle3_mc.myname = "xmlFile3";

var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlData:XML = new XML(); 

function LoadXML (evt:Event):void
{
    trace ("Load completed");
    xmlData = XML(xmlLoader.data);   
}

var bArray:Array = [circle1_mc, circle2_mc, circle3_mc];
for (var k:Number = 0; k<bArray.length; k++)
{
    bArray[k].buttonMode = true;
    bArray[k].addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK,changeXMLPath);
}
function changeXMLPath (evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    for (var i:Number = 0; i<bArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (evt.target.myname == bArray[i].myname)
        {         
            xmlLoader.load (new URLRequest(evt.target.myname+".xml"));
            xmlLoader.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE,LoadXML);
        }
    }
}



for each(var circleMC:MovieClip in circles)
{
    circleMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
    circleMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
    circleMC.startX = circleMC.x;
    circleMC.startY = circleMC.y;
}

function pickUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    reply_txt.text = "";
    event.target.startDrag(true);
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
}

function dropIt(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.stopDrag();
    if(event.target.hitTestObject(target_mc)){
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.x = target_mc.x;
        event.target.y = target_mc.y;


        for each(var circleMC:MovieClip in circles)
        {
            if(event.target != circleMC)
            {
                circleMC.x = circleMC.startX;
                circleMC.y = circleMC.startY;
            }
            if(event.target.name == "circle1_mc"){
                reply_txt.text = "Statue1 In Place Successfully";

            };
            if(event.target.name == "circle2_mc"){
                reply_txt.text = "Statue2 In Place Successfully";
            };
            if(event.target.name == "circle3_mc"){
                reply_txt.text = "Statue3 In Place Successfully";
            };
        }
    }
    else
    {
        event.target.x = event.target.startX;
        event.target.y = event.target.startY;
        event.target.buttonMode = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `startDrag()` and `stopDrag()` method along with `hitTestObject()` method as follows,

- I have placed three circles on the stage as "circle1","circle2" and "circle3".
- I have also placed three symbols as drop target on the stage with instance names as
  "dropTarget1", "dropTarget2" and "dropTarget3".

Place the following code on flash timeline,

```
var totCircles:int = 3;
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlData:XML = new XML(); 

for (var k:Number = 1; k<=totCircles; k++)
{
   this["circle" + k].buttonMode = true;
   this["circle" + k].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
   this["circle" + k].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
}

function startDragging(e:MouseEvent):void
{
     e.currentTarget.startDrag(false);
}

function stopDragging(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // extract index from current target
    var currTarIndex = e.currentTarget.name.slice(6); 
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();

    if(e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(this["dropTarget" + currTarIndex]))
    {
         loadXML("xmlFile"+ currTarIndex + ".xml");
         //You can also add position snap here
    }
 }

 function loadXML(url:String):void
 {
      xmlLoader.load (new URLRequest(url));
      xmlLoader.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE,LoadXML);
 }
```

Hope this will help you.